# At the beginning of True Blood who knows about Sookie's abilities?

Tags: true-blood

I've just watched the first episode of True Blood and I'm a little confused about how many people know that Sookie can read their thoughts.

There's a scene with Jason where he becomes frustrated that he wasn't guarding his thoughts around her and there's another with Tara where she's annoyed because had Sookie.

Bill is suspicious, does anyone else know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long time since I watched that first episode, but here's what I know for sure:

Sookie's parents knew, before they died.  Her Gran knew.  Tara and Jason knew.  It's revealed later in the series that the school psychologist knew but was freaked out and attributed it to being very observant.

Bill didn't know during the first episode, but he learned about it after just a few episodes.  (She can't read Bill's thoughts or any vampires' thoughts.)

Later in the series, some of the others she works with (Arlene, Lafayette, Sam) know as well, but I doubt they knew at the start of the series.

For the most part, Sookie kept it to herself and only told some family and very close friends.